# How does the CLDR define its rules for month abbreviations - specifically for en_CA?

Tags: java, localization, cldr

The [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/) provides a repository of locale data. In Java, you can access a list of CLDR month abbreviations for a given locale, as follows:

```java
String[] usMonthAbbrevs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US).getShortMonths();
System.out.println(usMonthAbbrevs[0]);
```

The above (in Java 17, using the default CLDR provider) prints `Jan`.

I have been assuming (maybe wrongly) that this list of abbreviations is defined in the relevant CLDR XML file for the `en` locale:

`cldr` > `common` > `main` > [`en.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/release-41/common/main/en.xml#L2167) > `<month type="1">Jan</month>`

But for Canadian English, the same month abbreviations all have periods at the end:

```java
String[] canMonthAbbrevs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.CANADA).getShortMonths();
System.out.println(canMonthAbbrevs[0]);
```

The above prints `Jan.` - note that period at the end.

---

**Question: Where is the CLDR list, or rule, which specifies this extra period for the `en_CA` locale?**

I did not see anything obvious in the [`en_CA.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/release-41/common/main/en_CA.xml) file. Maybe I missed it, or I did not understand what I was looking at.

---

To research this, I tried to trace the code back through Java's resource bundle classes.

This led me to the following class:

```
sun.text.resources.cldr.ext.FormatData_en_CA
```

I found this class in my Java installation in `jmods/jdk.localedata.jmod`. After unzipping that `jmod` file, I opened the following class file:

```
classes/sun/text/resources/cldr/ext/FormatData_en_CA.class
```

In there, I saw bytecode which contains the month abbreviations with periods - for example:

```
* 7: ldc           #9                  // String Jan.
```

My guess is that all the classes in `jdk.localedata.jmod` are pre-built (presumably from CLDR data/rules). But I was not able to see how that process happens. Maybe a tool which is part of the JDK build process?

So, my question remains: Where is the CLDR list, or rule, which specifies this extra period for the `en_CA` locale's month abbreviations?

<sup>Why am I asking? Just because I got curious about this, after noticing the difference between the US and Canadian abbreviations.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong version. [Java 17 supports CLDR 39](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258794), not 41. If you look at the version-39 [en_CA.xml](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/release-39/common/main/en_CA.xml#L1623) file, you can clearly see them all laid out there:

```
<monthWidth type="abbreviated">
    <month type="1">Jan.</month>
    <month type="2">Feb.</month>
    <month type="3">Mar.</month>
    <month type="4">Apr.</month>
    <month type="5">May</month>
    <month type="6">Jun.</month>
    <month type="7">Jul.</month>
    <month type="8">Aug.</month>
    <month type="9">Sep.</month>
    <month type="10">Oct.</month>
    <month type="11">Nov.</month>
    <month type="12">Dec.</month>
</monthWidth>
```

Evidently, in newer versions, this trailing dot is removed :)

Comment: That was it - thank you. The change happened in CLDR v40 - [here is the commit](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/pull/1391/files#diff-cfce2160284601fa135a8ab8b93b3a936d4b21549399ad7d69eb09ef70918d4a). I did not see any specific notes explaining the removal of the periods.